# Admin Message Broadcast for all wp users

Tags: plugins

Wordpress admin sends a message and it will be shown in frontend to registered wp users.
Read and unread facility is also required
Any Plugin suggested for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/private-messages-for-wordpress/) to achieve what you want.